# How to make changes in seed.flex file

Tags: ruta

I am a uima ruta newbie. I just want to make some changes in **seed.flex** file which should effect in our eclipse output. I have done many changes but still the output is working as usual. Tell me how to make that changes effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to modify the SeedLexer implementation:

- modify/extend SeedLexer.flex with your regex
- download jflex 1.4.3 from http://jflex.de/
- start the gui of jflex and generate the java class for SeedLexer.flex
- build the complete ruta reactor project